# My code is not working to move files from 1 folder to another

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried 2 difference codes to move files from 1 folder to another in Sharepoint but receive 2 different errors. Please help to see what i am doing wrong.

Error: Run Time Error 5 - Invalid Procedure Call or Argument

```
Sub MoveAFile()

'Move file to archive after download complete

Dim ogfilepath, newfilepath As String
Dim i As Double

i = 11
Do

    ogfilepath = Worksheets(CN.Name).Cells(i, 2).Value 'https://wwpcis.sharepoint.com/sites/XXX/filename.pdf
    newfilepath = Worksheets(CN.Name).Cells(i, 5).Value
'https://wwpcis.sharepoint.com/sites/XXX/YYY/filename.pdf

    Name ogfilepath As _
    newfilepath

i = i + 1

Loop Until Cells(i, 1).Value = ""
MsgBox ("Moved to archive")

End Sub
```

Error: Runtime Error 76 Path not found

```
Sub FSOMoveAllFiles()

'test new code for moving files

    Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
    Dim FromPath As String
    Dim ToPath As String
    Dim FileInFromFolder As Object

    FromPath = https://wwpcis.sharepoint.com/sites/XXX/filename.pdf
    ToPath = https://wwpcis.sharepoint.com/sites/XXX/YYY/filename.pdf
   
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    For Each FileInFromFolder In FSO.GetFolder(FromPath).Files
        FileInFromFolder.Move ToPath
    Next FileInFromFolder

End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah... The http(s) protocol doesn't really work like that. Maybe read through https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/map-a-network-drive-to-a-sharepoint-library-751148de-f579-42f9-bc8c-fcd80ccf0f53#:~:text=Get%20the%20address%20details%20of%20the%20SharePoint%20site,want%20to%20map%20to.%20...%20More%20items...%20

Comment: Hi, Try mapping both folders from sharepoint [mapping](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2013/09/06/map-sharepoint-libraries-with-local-file-drive-a-step-by-step-guide/) and then try to archive them. You can't move files using http(s) protocol.